# Add colour to word in TinyMCE based on a list of words

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

Using TinyMCE, latest version.

In a body of text, I would like to highlight certain words. Those words will be defined in a list.

example:

```
var words = ["dave","walk","train","late"];
```

content example:

```
var content = "Dave had to walk to the train station, which made him late for his train.";
```

desired outcome:

[image]

I have had a look through the documentation on TinyMCE but was unable to find anything that looked suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna answer this in the case that someone else is looking for a solution to the same.

I managed to find a way to do this, although it might not be the BEST way to do it, it works for my requirements.

After TinyMCE is initialised I needed to trigger a function that will replace the content with an edited version, to do this I used the 'init_instance_callback' method.

```
init_instance_callback: "myCustomInitInstance",
```

and I define a function before TinyMCE is initialised.

```
function myCustomInitInstance(inst) {
    var body = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
    var find = "walks,train,late".split(',');
    find.forEach(function (v) {
        var re = new RegExp("("+v+")(?![</span>])", "gumi"); 
        body = body.replace(re, `<span class="highlight">`+v+`</span>`);
    });
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(body);
}
```

This will get the content from the editor after it's loaded, and then go through all the words in the find array and replace them based on the regex method.

This in conjunction with some TinyMCE custom content styles

```
content_style: '.highlight { color: orange; } ',
```

and I have a working solution for now..

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this question @Deano . As the user types in , the cursor always goes to the beginning . Is there a way to set the cursor right after where user types the last character?